# UiPath scrape into sql database

Tags: sql-server, screen-scraping

Not sure how many of you have used UiPath, but I am having an issue when scrapping within UiPath and trying to insert that scrapped variable into my database. It keeps telling me it is not the right column name. Any suggestions?

Comment: What query do you set to "Sql" property in "Execute Query" activity?

Comment: "INSERT INTO tblCompany (CompanyName)
VALUES ('2')"

using "2" as a test value. I will be putting the scraped data into it.

Comment: It reproduces with the 2 as a test value as well or only when you pass the variable returned by ScrapeActivity? Does the test query work if you execute it from SQL Server?

Comment: It reproduces the 2 as a test value. Yes it does work when I execute a query using sql server. I am not sure how I did but I have got the scraped data in but it did not return the value of the scraped data but just the text of the scrapeactivity.

Comment: Can you upload your workflow somewhere and post the link to see it? What version of UiPath Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To pass the contents of the variable returned by *ScrapeActivity* to the query you must first declare a parameter in the "Parameters" property of *ExecuteNonQuery* activity.

Let's say your *ScrapeActivity* returns the scraped text in **scrapeActivityResult** variable.
Click on "Edit Query" and afterwards the "Parameters" button. 
A new dialog will open where you can add parameters.
Add a new *In* parameter named **companyName** of type "String" and set its value to **scrapeActivityResult** variable.

After that, you have to use the newly created parameter(**companyName**) into your query

```
"INSERT INTO tblCompany('CompanyName') VALUES (@companyName)"
```

Answer (score 1):

That was happening to me too! There is a parameter in the query activity that needs to be set/not set

It's really good to see uipath stuff here...